# Scan USPS barcode from a Mac

Tags: scanning

Is there any App that permits scanning barcodes?  An app that also supports UPS and Fedex would be useful.

The following search did not bring up any obvious results.  http://alternativeto.net/software/scan--qr-code-reader-/?platform=mac

Comment: You don't need an "App" to scan a bar code,   I have a Symbol bar code reader that I plug in and it scans nearly everything.  The limitations are the bar codes the hardware doesn't recognize.  What exactly are you trying to  do?

Comment: @Allan Well.. scan UPS, Fedex and USPS barcodes - as in the OP.

Comment: Which ones do you want to scan?  2D, 3D, or both?  Mine scans both, but even the cheapest one will scan the 2D USPS/UPS/FedEx labels with no problem.  It even scans UPC labels on products.  Also, are you trying to scan physical labels or ones on the screen?

Comment: @Allan OK thx for those details. Most interested in 2D physical labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program EvoBarcode from evological scans barcodes using the webcam on a Mac. As far as I can see it supports the barcode type used by USPS (Code 128).

http://www.evological.com/evobarcode.html

The program costs 30$, but they offer a free 15 day trial.

Answer (score 1):

You can scan barcodes on the Mac with Delicious Library (available for free from https://delicious-monster.com/). You can use it to scan in the barcodes of your CD / DVD collection, but I don't know if it will read the barcode formats used by USPS/FedEx/UPS.

Comment: Thx for finding that. I have upvoted as interesting but will wait for possibly more responses before deciding on acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an App to scan USPS barcodes.  There are plenty of apps out there that can do what you are looking for by integrating with a camera or your webcam, but I have found a purpose built scanner the best and most reliable solution.

[image]

I use several from the Symbol line, and I have found [this model](http://amzn.to/1TkO7lF) quite excellent at scanning everything from shipping labels (FedEx, UPS, USPS, DHL, etc).

It will also scan UPC (product) barcodes and ISBN (books and media) bar codes with no problem.

You don't need special software.  You can litterlly open Safari to the USPS website, scan the barcode and the numbers will be "typed into" the field you are on.  It works in ***any*** application.  I have used it in Word and Excel (Office 2011) on many occasions.

Comment: So the built-in camera can not be used??

Comment: I am sure you could, because there are apps out there that allow you to scan bar codes with your phone.  However, I am sure you are not seeing much software (I did a cursory search myself) that turns a camera into a bar code scanner simply because the actual bar code scanner is much more efficient and easier to use.  Think about it...are you going to either pick up the package or your computer to position the camera to "see" the barcode?

Comment: I found something on SourceForge, https://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/ but, unfortunately, no native OS X apps

Comment: Thx for looking into this. I have upvoted but not accepted (at least not yet).  I am also going to look into the other answer a bit.